# How to play audio without strict limitations on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm making a game made of bare JavaScript code and I want to manipulate audio in JavaScript.
Specifically, I want to let the page start playing music when some `div` element is clicked and when using some function in the JavaScript code.

I know audio tag of HTML5 has a limitation that a music file associated with `Audio` element cannot be played without user clicking the play button of the audio element, so I cannot do like this:

```
const audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "url of source";
audio.play(); 
//Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because 
//the user didn't interact with the document first.　
//https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
```

> Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

> Muted autoplay is always allowed.
> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
> User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
> On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
> The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
> Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

But I want to manage audio more freely in order to make a good UI of the game.

To achieve my goal, I think I need to introduce another library or API into the JavaScript code or still use audio tag with some tricky tips.

I'm thinking one of the choices could be [Web Audio API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

Could you tell me some advice?

### Progress

I tried code like the following and it worked when I clicked a div element with click event handler:

```
<div id="my-div">play</div>

<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="url of source" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```
const myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
const btn = document.getElementById("my-div");
btn.addEventListener("click",() => {
  myAudio.play();
});
```

However, when I wrote like the following, it didn't work with the same error even if it didn't seem I broke the autoplay policy:

```
document.getElementById('my-div').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const audio = new Audio('url of source');
    audio.play();
});
//Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because 
//the user didn't interact with the document first.　
//https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
```

The main difference between two codes above is whether I wrote the url of the audio source file in the audio tag or wrote it in the source tag inside the audio tag. I'm guessing this makes some difference but I don't get what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what error you're getting ? `//get error`

Comment: OK, I rewrote a full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. You can only be sure that the playback will not be blocked by the autoplay policy if the playback is started in response to a user gesture. A button with a click handler is the classic example but the click handler could be attached to a div as well. Let's say your div has an id called `my-div`. In that case the following should work.

```
document.getElementById('my-div').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const audio = new Audio('url of source');

    audio.play(); 
});
```

Using the Web Audio API will not change the autoplay policy. Usually the same rules apply no matter which browser API is used.

Comment: I tried it and I clicked the div element `my-div` , but the result is the same. I got the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems as the url of the source points to some audio format that is not supported.  As a test, use a small mp3 file.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread the error. And the problem was that 
 unexpected escape was happened by back slashes "\" inside the URL strings. I replaced back slashes with normal slashes and your code worked. Thank you very much for the advice.